# Python3, не могу преобразовать unicode строку в обычную

Tags: python-3.x

Есть строка вида:

```
"\ud835\udcaa\ud835\udcbb\ud835\udcbb\ud835\udcbe\ud835\udcb8\ud835\udcbe\ud835\udcb6\ud835\udcc1 \ud835\udcc5\ud835\udcb6\ud835\udc54\ud835\udc52 \n\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, \u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430\ud83d\udc78\ud83c\udffc\n\u041d\u0430\u043a\u043e\u043d\u0435\u0446-\u0442\u043e \u0442\u044b \u043d\u0430\u0441 \u043d\u0430\u0448\u043b\u0430!\ud83d\udc8b\n\ud83d\udecd\u041e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u044f\u0435\u043c \u0432 \u043b\u044e\u0431\u0443\u044e \u0442\u043e\u0447\u043a\u0443 \u041c\u0438\u0440\u0430\n\ud83d\udd25\u0421\u0430\u043c\u044b\u0435 \u043d\u0438\u0437\u043a\u0438\u0435 \u0446\u0435\u043d\u044b\n\ud83d\udecd\u0414\u0440\u043e\u043f, \u043e\u043f\u0442\n\ud835\udff9\ud835\udffe\ud835\udff6 \ud835\udffc\ud835\udff9 \ud835\udffa\ud835\udffb\ud835\udff7 \ud835\udffe\ud835\udffe\ud835\udffe\ud835\udffe \ud835\udcb1\ud835\udcbe\ud835\udcb7\ud835\udc52\ud835\udcc7, \ud835\udc9f\ud835\udcbe\ud835\udcc7\ud835\udc52\ud835\udcb8\ud835\udcc9"
```

и мы знаем, что в ней лежит текст и смайлы, но я не могу его вытащить. Если выводить эту строку в python shell,то получаем читабельный вариант, но внутри кода я этого сделать не могу

Comment: Что именно значит "но внутри кода я этого сделать не могу"? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Подразумевается, что не могу подобрать функцию, которая преобразует и вернёт строку текста

Answer (score 0):

```
good = u'\ud835\udcaa\ud835\udcbb\ud835\udcbb\ud835\udcbe\ud835\udcb8\ud835\udcbe\ud835\udcb6\ud835\udcc1 \ud835\udcc5\ud835\udcb6\ud835\udc54\ud835\udc52 \n\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, \u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430\ud83d\udc78\ud83c\udffc\n\u041d\u0430\u043a\u043e\u043d\u0435\u0446-\u0442\u043e \u0442\u044b \u043d\u0430\u0441 \u043d\u0430\u0448\u043b\u0430!\ud83d\udc8b\n\ud83d\udecd\u041e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u044f\u0435\u043c \u0432 \u043b\u044e\u0431\u0443\u044e \u0442\u043e\u0447\u043a\u0443 \u041c\u0438\u0440\u0430\n\ud83d\udd25\u0421\u0430\u043c\u044b\u0435 \u043d\u0438\u0437\u043a\u0438\u0435 \u0446\u0435\u043d\u044b\n\ud83d\udecd\u0414\u0440\u043e\u043f, \u043e\u043f\u0442\n\ud835\udff9\ud835\udffe\ud835\udff6 \ud835\udffc\ud835\udff9 \ud835\udffa\ud835\udffb\ud835\udff7 \ud835\udffe\ud835\udffe\ud835\udffe\ud835\udffe \ud835\udcb1\ud835\udcbe\ud835\udcb7\ud835\udc52\ud835\udcc7, \ud835\udc9f\ud835\udcbe\ud835\udcc7\ud835\udc52\ud835\udcb8\ud835\udcc9'
```

Ещё чем-то основываясь на тексте вопроса помочь сложно. Приведите пример кода, или хотя бы скажите что вам вернуло эту строку. Если, например, это JSON, то есть специальные методы.

Comment: Так должно быть `print(good)` `UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-15: surrogates not allowed`? :) Это консоль пичарма такое выдает. А вот другая консоль смогла кое-что `...Привет, красотка\ud83d\udc78\ud83c\udffc\nНаконец-то ты нас нашла!\ud83d\udc8b\n\ud83d\udecdОтправляем в любую точку Мира\n\ud83d\udd25Самые низкие цены\n\ud83d\udecdДроп, опт...`

Comment: @gil9red это определённо то, что нужно :D.

Ну тогда я хз. `good = bad.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').decode('ISO-8859-1')`
Может так тогда. У меня просто нет сейчас возможности протестить.

Comment: Попробовал, ошибка в encode: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-15: surrogates not allowed` :)

Comment: Странно. `surrogateescape` же.

Ну тогда остаётся узнать откуда он это получает.